# Momentary button on Web Page

Tags: gpio, web-interface

I have a program (on a Pi Zero W) that uses Flask to host a web page, that serves as a controller for some motors. I want a button on the page to act as a momentary button, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Here are the routes and actions for that button:

```
@app.route("/leftDown", methods=["GET"])
def leftDown():
    RollActive = True
    i=1
    while RollActive and i <= 50 :
        Roll(True,5)
        i += 1
    return True

@app.route("/leftUp", methods=["GET"])
def leftUp():
    RollActive = False
    return True
```

This is a simplified version, but the basic intent is that the button down event will start the action (Roll(True,5)) and set a RollActive flag, the button up event will set that flag to false, thereby cancelling the action.

I suspect this is related to threading, in so far as I can't execute the button up event while it's executing the while loop, but it feels like there should be a more simple solution than multi-threading.

**Clarification**: I have added the 'i' counter in the code above to avoid an infinite loop - I intend to remove this later. The problem is that the leftUp function can't be run while the code is executing the while loop - therefore, it can't set RollActive to False which would break the loop. How do I allow the leftUp function to execute while executing the while loop?

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you asking this at a Raspberry Pi site? ...  the question is not about Raspberry Pi ... it belongs at https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: Raspberry Pi is more than just GPIO pins - this relates to an implementation on a Pi Zero W. There are so many StackExchange sites, it's hard to know which is most relevant. I'm not sure how your link relates to this question. The target language is python, but your response seems to direct to a JS page? Have I overlooked something?

Comment: my bad ... I was not paying attention to the language in your code snippet